# How does `get` work in the CPS version of the State monad?

Tags: haskell, ocaml, continuations, state-monad, delimited-continuations

I am trying to understand continuation in general following this [tutorial](http://okmij.org/ftp/continuations/#tutorial).

However, I am having difficulties to understand following example in section 2.10:

```
# let get () =
    shift (fun k -> fun state -> k state state) ;;
get : unit => ’a = <fun>
```

`state` is of type `int` I suppose. What I don't get is the type of `k`. According to my understanding, `k` captures all computation comes subsequently after `get ()`, and since we are talking about a state monad, `k` is reasonable to represent a computation that will be continued by taking an `int`, hence

```
k : int => 'a
```

but from the code, it doesn't seem to do that and it takes `state` for a second time, which actually implies:

```
k : int => int => 'a
```

but I don't get where the second one is coming from, and in which sense `get` is of type `unit => 'a` instead of `unit => int => 'a`?

Compared to the actual state monad implementation, the confusion adds more:

```
newtype StateT s m a = StateT { runStateT :: s -> m (a,s) }
```

i.e. state transition is represented as a function from state to a tuple of result and state, which matches my first understanding.

Can anyone give a lead?

Secondly, how am I supposed to implement `get` here using Haskell's `Control.Monad.Trans.Cont`? I am having problems comforting the type system.

---

UPDATE

It seems I got the second one:

```
Prelude Control.Monad.Trans.Cont> let get () = shift $ \k -> return $ \i -> k i i
```

But I still don't get why I need to apply the state twice to the continuation.

Comment: @Bergi it's actually called OchaCaml. I am following the tutorial but I don't think languages in use impact the understanding of the concept in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You apply `k` on `state` twice because the first one corresponds to the result of `get ()` (we want `get`'s effect to be retrieving the current state and returning it as the result) and the second one corresponds to passing the state after the `get` (which, because `get` doesn't change the state, is the same as the state before the `get`) to the next stateful computation.

In other words, since the state monad is `State s a ~ s -> (a, s)`, its CPS version is `State s r a ~ s -> (a -> s -> r) -> r`, and so for `get : State s s`, because `a ~ s`, the continuation will be a function of type `s -> s -> r`.

Comment: that's the main part i don't get. should continuation be enough just by passing the current state already? i also don't understand how to step from the state monad version to cps version.

Comment: also how can i know the type of continuation just by looking at the code? which part should i look, the hole or not the hole?

Comment: Think of what you would want to pass if the result of `get` was supposed to be the current state + 1 (fixing it to `State Int` for the sake of example). The subsequent state would still be the same as the incoming state, but the result would be different. So you'd need to pass `state + 1` as the result argument and `state` as the new state argument to the continuation.